# Milliseconds into a readable date

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

i am trying to convert 1542060610213 (milliseconds) into a readable date but everything i try returns "Invalid Date" whats the best method to go about this?

Comment: *everything i try returns "Invalid Date"* - what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var myReadableDate = new Date(milliseconds).toString()
```